# ReactJS - Minhas Rotas não funcionam em produção

Tags: javascript, html, react, aplicação-web, react-router

**index.js** do projeto:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
  createRoutesFromElements,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";

import App from './components/app';
import Navbar from './components/navbar';
import Footer from './components/footer';
import Projects from './components/projects';
import About from './components/about';
import WhatsappIcon from './components/whatsapp';

function Component(child){
  return (
    <>
      <WhatsappIcon />
      <header>
        <Navbar/>
      </header>
      {child}
      <footer>
        <Footer/>
      </footer>
    </>
  );
}

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <>
      <Route path='/' element={ Component(<App />) } />
      <Route path='projetos' element={ Component(<Projects />) } />
      <Route path='sobre' element={ Component(<About />) } />
    </>
  )
);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
document.title = 'Sun Light';

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router}/>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

e as tags de redirecionamento em outras partes do código são assim:

```
<a href="/sobre">
<GrMail className="icon"/>
</a>


<a href="/sobre">
<AiFillPhone className="icon"/>
</a>


<Link to="sobre#form">Clique aqui</Link>
```

Alguns eu uso a tag **a** padrão do HTML e outras eu uso o componente **Link** do *react-router-dom*, mas as duas opções não funcionam igualmente.
Esse teste que eu to fazendo é em uma hospedagem gratuita no site https://br.000webhost.com , eu uso só pra ver o funcionamento online antes de subir pra uma hospedagem mais completa. Será que dependendo da plataforma eu preciso fazer alguma mudança nos direcionamentos ?

**EDIT 1:** eu tentei recriar o router de um jeito mais parecido com a documentação que apontaram nos comentarios, mas ainda sim funciona somente na base local. Em produção n funciona nenhuma rota alem da raiz

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path:"/",
    element: <App/>,
    children: [
      {
        path:"/",
        element: <Home />
      },
      {
        path:"sobre",
        element: <About />
      },
      {
        path:"projetos",
        element: <Projects />
      },
    ]
  }
]
);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
document.title = 'Sun Light';

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router}/>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

*(ainda acho que seja possível que por ser uma hospedagem gratuita ela seja limitada nessa questão de rotas)*

Comment: Onde foi que as rotas funcionaram?

Comment: se as rotas não tão funcionando no ambiente local também... tenta seguir a documentação aqui https://reactrouter.com/en/main/utils/create-routes-from-elements, lá é usado um <Route> e não um Fragment (<></>) dentro do createRoutesFromElements. Você está usando CRA ou algo do tipo?

Comment: @CésarRodriguez só a raiz(/)

Comment: @EduardoSantos em ambiente local funciona normalmente. Eu não sei o que é CRA

Comment: Coloca um link para o repositório, pra ver se alguém descobre.

Comment: A rigor, seus dois exemplos estão diferentes da documentação. O `createRoutesFromElements` deveria ter o `Route` pai como uma tag com conteúdo, contendo os dos filhos (esses sim, tags que fecham sozinhas). Já o exemplo que usa objetos atribui o mesmo caminho para duas rotas diferentes, sendo que uma é filha da outra. NÃO SEI se esse é o problema; talvez isso não afete em nada, mas está diferente dos exemplos da documentação.